# How do I display option inputs in HTML from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object, foreach

I'm trying to fetch data from my API, and put it in 'option' input.
But all I'm geting is [object Object]. And I would like to get days of the week.

```
const daysOptions = document.querySelector("#days");

const getData = async (url) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();

    if (data.length > 0) {
      return data;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
};

const createOptions = async () => {
  const dataDays = await getData("http://localhost:8080/v1/days/getdays");
  console.log(dataDays);

  dataDays.forEach((day) => {
    const selectOption = document.createElement("option");
    selectOption.value = day;
    // selectOption.id = id;
    selectOption.textContent = day;
    daysOptions.append(selectOption);
  });
};

createOptions();
```

What I'm fetching is:

```
0: {id: 1, day: 'Monday'}
1: {id: 2, day: 'Tuesday'}
2: {id: 3, day: 'Wednesday'}
3: {id: 4, day: 'Thursday'}
4: {id: 5, day: 'Friday'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching when you are looping you should code like this below

```
dataDays.forEach((item) => {
  const selectOption = document.createElement("option");
  selectOption.value = item.day;
  // selectOption.id = id;
  selectOption.textContent = item.day;
  daysOptions.append(selectOption);
});
```

Here using the item I am accessing each  object from the fetched list, and item.day is getting the value of the day.

if this solve your issue, let me know by replying or upvoting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react js then you can use this code.

```js
const Days = () => {
  const days = [
    { id: 1, day: "Monday" },
    { id: 2, day: "Tuesday" },
    { id: 3, day: "Wednesday" },
    { id: 4, day: "Thursday" },
    { id: 5, day: "Friday" },
    { id: 5, day: "Saturday" },
    { id: 5, day: "Sunday" },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <select name="days" id="">
        {days.map((day) => (
          <option key={day.id} value={day.day}>
            {day.day}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <Days />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="rd" />
```